# why my influxdb bucket just have 1or2 data in every fields

Tags: python, influxdb

here are some of my codes
'''python

```
def create_influxdb_point(measurement, tag, fields):
    current_timestamp = int(time.time())
    point = Point(measurement).tag('tag', tag).time(current_timestamp, WritePrecision.S)
    for field_key, field_value in fields.items():
        point.field(field_key, field_value)
    return point

# Upload data for the first 1000 rows with tag 'train'
for index, row in excel_data.head(1000).iterrows():
    measurement = 'm1'
    tag = 'train'

    fields = {'Ssin': row[0], 'Ssr1': row[1], 'CODin': row[2], 'SNHin': row[3], 'Sse': row[4],
              'CODe': row[5], 'SNHe': row[6], 'SNOe': row[7], 'SNHr1': row[8], 'SNHr2': row[9],
              'SNHr5': row[10], 'SNOr1': row[11], 'SNOr2': row[12], 'SNOr5': row[13], 'SOr1': row[14],
              'SOr2': row[15], 'SOr5': row[16], 'Qin': row[17], 'Qintr': row[18], 'Qe': row[19],
              'BOD5_SUNe': row[20], 'BOD5_Raine': row[21], 'BOD5_RainSte': row[22]
    }

    point = create_influxdb_point(measurement, tag, fields)
    write_api.write(bucket=bucket, org=org, record=point)
```

'''
i set a loop that have 1000,and the every point have 23field,in each field it has 1000row,means every field is a array.

when i log in the influxdb and check the bucket,i found  every fileds just have 1or2 date,but in the codes it is actually 1000data in every field.And i also found all the timestamp are in the same,maybe it is caused by the timestamp?

Comment: sorry,sir, i have correct my mistakes